# How to store user statistics like strenght, vitality (mysql, video game)

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am conceptualizing a basic game using web development (Laravel, Mysql, Vue.js) and the user has some basic statistics, like : vitality, strength, crit, dexterity, % physical damage and some more.

And I was thinking, how should I store it in my database ?

Must I create a `statistics` table and a pivot table `user_statistic` ?

OR

Basically add a column for each statistics that I want in my game in the `user` table ?

Comment: This question is very broad. There's a lot of different ways to go about this depending on what kind of game you have. For example you can decide to just have a character "level" value and derive all other statistics based on that (maybe influenced by other things like character class or whatever), or you can have a pre-set number of statistics that you can have directly on the `characters` table as columns or (as you mentioned) a many to many relationship between characters and statistics. The question is what makes sense for your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple and all users can have the same statistics, then just create a `user_statistics` table that has a `user_id` and a field for each statistic. There is no need for a pivot table. Just to be clear, a pivot table is the link between two other tabels.

Keep it out of the users table, as stats do not describe a user, but sums up actions the user has made.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you will want too have two tables in this situation, one for the users obviously and then other for the statistics where you will have all the basic statistics of the user and a `user_id` column that will be your foreign key for the the users table.

In case u need it laravel migrations for the statistics table will look something like this:

```
Schema::create('statistics ', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```